# MySQL 8 Mysqldump is slow after updating from mysql 5.1

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

We recently upgraded from MySQL 5.1 to 8.0.26.  We are currently running the following command for our backup:  mysqldump -F -A -R --source-data=2 --single-transaction -u $myuser -p$mypw -P 3306 -S /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock > $buFile

However, when it runs it is very slow and we also receive the following warnings, which I think are part of the problem:  SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM 'tables'for most of the tables

SQL_NO_CACHE is depricated in MySQL 8, so I am sure that is the problem, but I don't know why it is being used during mysqldump.  Is there an issue with the way we are using the options with the current version?  We basically copied the old mysqldump code over and started using that.

Of course any feedback would be helpful.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The "Query cache" used to exist.  It cached most `SELECTs` in case the *identical* query showed up again.

Before 8.0, `SQL_NO_CACHE` says to bypass the QC, forcing the `SELECTs` that mysqldump issues to be done fully.  It has no impact on 8.0.  (Bottom line: that token has no impact on the question.)

How much RAM do did your 5.1 have?  Which engine were you using?  Are you still using the same engine, or did it change to InnoDB.  How much data?

If you *were* using MyISAM and are now using InnoDB, that has some impact, but probably not a noticeable amount.

What is the 8.0's setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?